# Bind ILIST to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

This is my first time to WPF and C#, and I am completely blank as of now. I did go through innumerable posts on stackoverflow and internet but couldn't actually find a solution. Might be I must have come across a solution, but not able to exactly comprehend.

Problem:
I got data from api using HttpClient. I deserialized that data successfully and I am able to bind it up on front-end (XAML), but the issue is it is an IList and I am able to only display 1 row from the list. I want to iterate over that list and take out individual data.

```
public class FacultyViewModel
    {
        public Faculty faculty = new Faculty();
        IList<Faculty> person;
        public FacultyViewModel()
        {
            string jsonResponse = WebService.getData(Faculty.url);
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
            JArray a = (JArray)o["faculty"];
            person =  a.ToObject<IList<Faculty>>();
        }
        public IList<Faculty> List
        {
            get
            {
                return person;
            }
        }
    }
```

JSON DATA looks like this:

```
 "faculty": [
        {
            "username": "blah",
            "name": "Some name",
            "tagline": "",
            "imagePath": "some image",
            "title": "Lecturer",
            "interestArea": "Some Interest",
            "office": "Some Office",
            "website": "",
            "phone": "Some number",
            "email": "email",
            "twitter": "",
            "facebook": ""
        },
        {
            "username": "abcd",
            "name": "EFG",
            "tagline": "",
            "imagePath": "image.jpg",
            "title": "Assistant Professor",
            "interestArea": "interests here",
            "office": "office",
            "website": "website",
            "phone": "phone",
            "email": "email",
            "twitter": "",
            "facebook": ""
        },{...}]
```

Now the problem is when I simply `return person[0].username` it does return the username of faculty at 0 index. But I want to iterate over this list in my XAML front-end view. How can I? I did try itemscontrol and many things as I came across them, but failing to find a solution which works.

I just want to iterate over this list at the front-end inside the XAML file. Iterate like this:

```
for(i=0; i<person.length; i++)
{
  display person[i].username
  display person[i].email and so on....
}

      public IList<Faculty> List
      {
          get
          {
             return person;
          }
      }
```

Comment: why `IList`?  Might as well just create `List<person>` your aren't saving anything by IList, secondly the ListView, can you show what you were attempting in XAML? `ObservableCollection<>` would be another way to go if you want to see changes to the collection.

Comment: I am trying to display each one of the faculty and their details: e.g: faculty name: abc underneath his/her name I want to show his/her interests, photo and so on. I am not able to list anything in the XAML.

Comment: ok so master / details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Page.DataContext>
  <vm:FacultyViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<!-- Master --> 
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding FacultyList}"  Grid.Column="0" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFaculty, Mode=TwoWay}" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

 <!-- Details -->
 <Grid Grid.Column="1"
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition />
     <RowDefinition />
     <RowDefinition />
     <RowDefinition />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.name}" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.username }" Grid.Row="1" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.title}" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

```
 //View Code-Behind
public partial class FacultyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


     private Person _person;
     private List<Person> _facultyList;

     public FacultyViewModel(){

        InitializeComponents();

        DataContext = new FacultyViewModel();

        //list will not get renewed till you restart app
        //any additions to the list while running will not be shown.
        _facultyList = a.ToObject<List<Faculty>>();
     }


     // includes your other stuff here....



     //Selected a Faculty member from the listview.
     public Person SelectedPerson {
          get{ return _person;}
          set{ _person = value;
               RaisePropertyChange(()=>SelectedPerson);
         }
     }

    // list to populate the listview
    public List<Person> FacultyList{
         get{ return _facultyList;}
    }

     public virtual void RaisePropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null){
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
     }

   public void RaisePropertyChange<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> property){
        RaisePropertyChange(property.GetMemberInfo().Name);
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if(handler != null){
         handler(this,e);
      }
  }

}
```

Rough but gets the point to you about how to deal with collections and selections.

Comment: Man!!!! This is exactly I came up just 5 minutes ago. You are the hero! :D

Answer (score -1):

If you can only return 1 string to display, you have to concatenate all the data.

```
var str = "";
foreach(var e in person){
    str += e.username+"\n";
    str += e.email+"\n";
    ...
}
return str;
```

Comment: This is not I am looking for Lucas.